# Analog of setViewControllers:animated: in NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I would like to pop a view from the navigation stack (login screen) and immediately push another view (home screen) with `NavigatorIOS`.

In iOS I would achieve this using [`UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers?language=objc).

I have tried `navigator.replace`, `navigator.replaceAtIndex` but that doesn't quite work - it does replace the view but he navigation bar is hidden on the pushed screen (my login screen has it hidden, which is defined in its route properties), and there is no transition animation.

Another option that I tried is using `navigator.pop` followed by `navigator.push`. It did result in an animated transition but the login screen was still on the navigation stack (it wasn't popped) and the back button was visible.

What is the proper way to do this with `NavigatorIOS`?